# D3 v5 - Variable thickness band chart (over time)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

My goal is to create a newish-looking chart to use as an alternative to stacked bar charts. It's similar to an area chart, but there is no anchor to the x axis. Instead, each band expands or contracts to reflect gains or decreases in its relative share in the overall total. Pictured below:

[image]

It is a bit challenging to me because I am accustomed to charts the have a y axis. Here though, there is no y axis; the width of each band determines the proportion. The color denotes the type. We can ignore the dips and other movements in the y space (can just center align). The x axis is simply time (months).

Example data:

```
var data = [
{'month':'Jan', 'thing1':76,'thing2':21,'thing3':168},
{'month':'Feb', 'thing1':62,'thing2':91,'thing3':159},
{'month':'Mar', 'thing1':98,'thing2':67,'thing3':455},
{'month':'Apr', 'thing1':324,'thing2':53,'thing3':130}
];
```

It seems especially hard to create these curvy paths such that they directly stack on top of each other. My hunch is a `.curve()` would be needed.

```
  var myBands = d3.area()
      .x(function(d,i) { return xScale(d.month); })
      .y0(???)
      .y1(???})
      .curve(d3.curveCardinal);
```

Given there is no built-in solution for this type of chart, I may need to define my path logic manually, but as denoted by the `???` I can't figure out how to develop the y logic (how fat the band is).

### Question

How might I map out the necessary y logic / band fatness for `area()` or other `path` solution to attempt the above inspiration visual?

Comment: A [Steamgraph](https://observablehq.com/@d3/streamgraph)?